# How can I inserting a "div" at the right position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML5 page structure like this:

```
<article id="article_id">
  <div></div>
  <div> </div>
  <div> </div>
  <form id="form_id">
    <input id="" onsubmit="submit()"/>
  </form>
</article>
```

Now I want to add a new div **after div** and **before form**. How should I do it?

I have tried:

```
$("#form_id").befor('<div id="div_id" class="block">');
$("#form_id").parent().befor();
$("#form_id").after('<div id="div_id" class="block">');
```

The HTML code works fine.

Comment: Are you looking for `before()`?

Comment: i have tried befre but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's `before`. Secondly, you must pass an argument to it. The html that you will put before the form.

```
$("#form_id").before('<div class="block"></div>');
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/uHrKG/1/

Comment: Thanks alot,  actually i want to add div before the form. In short i can explain it as : its a feeds and comments section where i want to add my newly added comments (div) before the text box where cemments are typed

Comment: @Shahzeb ok it now adds the div only before the form